# Signed apk behaving very differently than if the application is run directly on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, signed-apk

I made an android application which at the end sends an object in json format to a web service and from there the data goes into database. When i run the application directly on the android emulators it works perfectly and all the data is perfectly parsed from my mobile application to the database. Now i made a signed apk and tested it on my phone the data going into database is not what should. The whole database is filled with zero values in all its fields. i dont understand why my signed apk is behaving is differently than my actual code. If anyone has any idea about this problem please help me. this problem is bugging me for a long time and i cant find any solution to it online.

Comment: Usually this is a result of Proguard obfuscation. You'll need to investigate more and at least narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: I found out the problem. I am using gson library to convert my object to json data. The json data formaed is different in signed and unsigned apk. The label names of all the json data are not of the class variables but are coming like 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , and so on. @Karakuri

Comment: Yes, you will need to make a proguard file with directives to keep those classes and fields. If you have other code that relies on such things (anything using reflection, for instance), you should do the same for those as well.